# Attractions around a specific route

Tags: web-apps, maps

Is there any web application which shows attractions near a specific route in UK ?

For example, I want to use M1 London to Bhirmingham, I would like to see what attractions or places are there I can visit, e.g. museums, or castles, etc...

I don't want to see attractions just near a place, I want them around my route..